# How can I add a namespace to all cshtml files in Razor without MVC?

Tags: asp.net, razor, web

Is there a way to add a namespace to all my cshtml Razor files from web.config without using MVC at all? Currently, **I even have to mention my root namespace every time**.

Please note that using `<system.web.webPages.razor>` will result in "`cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare that config section:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"
              type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host"
           type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
           requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages"
           type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
           requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Comment: Is this the only way? If so, what `pageBaseType` do I use for `<pages>`?

Comment: You can omit that attribute.

Comment: `Configuration Error`
`Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.`
`Parser Error Message: Required attribute 'pageBaseType' not found.`

Comment: Oops; use `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage`